# UICollectionView not adapting to iPad screen during rotation

Tags: uicollectionview, uiinterfaceorientation, screen-rotation, xcode5.1

```
#pragma mark Rotation handling methods

-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:
(NSTimeInterval)duration {
NSLog(@"IS ROTATING");
// Fade the collectionView out
[self.collectionView setAlpha:0.0f];

// Suppress the layout errors by invalidating the layout
[self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];

// Calculate the index of the item that the collectionView is currently displaying
CGPoint currentOffset = [self.collectionView contentOffset];
self.currentIndex = currentOffset.x / self.collectionView.frame.size.width;
}

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews;
{
[super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = (id)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;

if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])) {
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
} else {
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
}

[flowLayout invalidateLayout]; //force the elements to get laid out again with the new size
}


-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {

// Force realignment of cell being displayed
CGSize currentSize = self.view.bounds.size;
float offset = self.currentIndex * currentSize.width;
[self.collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(offset, 0)];


NSLog(@"CURRENT bounds: %f",self.view.bounds.size.width);
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:self.currentIndex inSection:0];
[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft animated:NO];


// Fade the collectionView back in
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.125f animations:^{
    [self.collectionView setAlpha:1.0f];
}];


}
```

This is the code. I just want the image to maintain full screen and the collection view is conforming to portrait. I can see that the cells are trying to adjust, but the collection view itself is not resizing. Any suggestions/fixes?

Answer (score 1):

Where do you set the new frame for the collectionView? Either you should set it in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation: duration:` or `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` or if its equal to the size of the superview, then set the resizing mask to flexible width or height.

```
_collectionView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

In `viewWillLayoutSubviews` you are setting the itemSize in landscape and portrait for the same, is it intended?

Comment: i set the frame in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` and the same size was not intentional, but i was trying anything to get it to work.